# TCPDF with FPDI templates and THEAD

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I have a html table with THEAD output with `writeHTML` which should be displayed on every page at the top of the table. It works but when I use a template loaded by FPDI the head is white and disappears on the second page and further. I can mark the head field with the mouse but the appear white. The border only appears as a little point on the left.

I already tried to add `$this->setPageMark()` to the `addPage` method. But its still the same issue.

```
public function AddPage($orientation = '', $format = ''){
    parent::AddPage($orientation, $format);
    if($this->template != null){
        $this->useTemplate($this->template);
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable page breaks at the beginning which is causing the issue you are having;
this is a sample code snippet ;

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); //main code    
require_once('tcpdf/fpdi.php');  //read existing pdf and sends to fpdf
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false); //no header
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);//no footer    
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0); // set auto page breaks
//loop starts here
{ 
    $pdf->setSourceFile($page_background); //set page                                                                                                                                                             
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage(1); //we only need the first page                                                                                   
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);     //use the imported page
    //your write html code and any other tcpdf related code comes here
}
$pdf->Output(outcome.pdf, 'I'); //use F instead of I  to show generated pdf.
```